# Access Always Encrypted data from Databricks

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I have a table in Azure SQL managed instance with 'Always Encrypted' columns. I stored the Column and master keys in Azure key Vault.

1. My first, question is  - How do I access the decrypted data in Azure SQL from Databricks. For that I connected to Azure SQL via jdbc. For Username and Password, I am passing my credentials manually

```
val jdbcHostname = "XXXXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "ABCD"

val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")

val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

import java.sql.DriverManager
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
connection.isClosed()

val user = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "dbo.bp_mp_user_test", connectionProperties)
display(user)
```

When I do this I am able to display the data, but it is encrypted data. How do I see the decrypted data

2. I am new to Azure and Databricks combo, so still learning Azure/Microsoft stack. Are there any other forms of jdbc connection syntax that allows you to decrypt.
3. I have the keys in Azure Keyvault. So how do I make use of those keys and the security associated with those keys, that way when someone accesses this table, it shows encrypted/decrypted data in the Databricks when accessed.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Did this work out? What is the outcome?